# Keep general dialog showing while allowing selection and clicking on the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List of long clickable ListItems on screen. The UI I am required to achieve is to slide in an actions widget from the top down that contains actions that can be applied on the selected items on screen.

I have selected the items, but the issue is that once I select the first item and display the slide in dialog from top, I can no longer click on any part of the screen again because the dialog barrier has blocked the entire screen.

What can I do to remove that barrier so I can still click on the list items without dismissing the dialog.

Only the actions on the dialog should be able to dismiss the dialog.

Here is my dialog setup currently:

```dart
 Future<T?> showNonBlockingTopModalSheet<T>(BuildContext context, Widget child,
    {bool barrierDismissible = false}) {
  return showGeneralDialog<T?>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
    barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
    transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    pageBuilder: (context, _, __) => child,
    transitionBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
      return SlideTransition(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Material(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [child],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        position: CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeOutCubic)
            .drive(
          Tween<Offset>(
            begin: const Offset(0, -1.0),
            end: Offset.zero,
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: I think that might not be the best use case for a `Dialog`, have you tried using `Overlay` or just a general `Stack`?

Comment: @Genix I haven't.  I find it hard to reproduce the sliding in from top functionality without using a dialog. If you can show some code snippets that could achieve same effect without the dialog approach then that would really be appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: This seems to be a nice tutorial https://appvesto.medium.com/guide-how-to-create-an-animated-overlay-4d6860d077e

Comment: @ololo, I will provide post the code with solution that goes along with your code.

Comment: @Mearaj I will be expecting. Thank you in anticipation

Comment: @ololo, your code is inside Stateful or Stateless widget?

Comment: @Mearaj My code is in a stateful widget.

Comment: Ok. I have posted the solution. Let me know if any issues. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [showGeneralDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/showGeneralDialog.html) creates a new page on top of our page, because of which we can't control our page which is behind the new one.
I have implemented the code as per your needs. You may need to modify it as per your requirements. It will help you proceed further.
We are using [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html), along with [Animated Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html) for your use case.
Stack has two children, first one is the visible list items and second one is the AnimatedPositioned widget.
The example is inspired from [AnimatedPositioned Demo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedPositioned-class.html)
Here is your code.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool showModel = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final listItems = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: !showModel ? AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
       ):PreferredSize(child: SizedBox(), preferredSize: Size(0,0),),,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            children: listItems.map((e) {
              return Container(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Text('Widget number $e'));
            }).toList(),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
          curve: Curves.easeOutCubic,
            height: 200,
            bottom: showModel ?
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 200:
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: const Center(child: Text("I am modal prompt")),
            ),)
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            showModel = !showModel;
          });
          },
        child: Text("Toggle"),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works as is, but I want the animation to happen from the SafeArea down. Currently your code is working but the animation is happening from within the AppBar which is not what I want. If you noticed, the showGeneralDialog slide in from the safe area downwards, which is exactly what i wanted. Thank you

Comment: You want it to appear on top of app bar right?.

Comment: Yes, very similar to the showGeneralDialog without the click blockers

Comment: I have updated. Please see if it works and let me know if any issues. You can also adjust Size(0,0) values as per your needs, which is inside PreferredSize widget.

Comment: Yess!!! Exactly, what I wanted now. Thanks a billion. I truly appreciate

Comment: Your are welcome, thanks to you too :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254154/discussion-between-mearaj-and-ololo).